# Is there a way to write a function which accepts a reference, a move, or a conversion using only traits from the standard library?

Tags: rust

I can write a function which accepts `X` and `&X`:

```
fn foo<T: Borrow<X>>(x: T)
```

I can write a function which accepts `X`, `Y` and `&Y`, assuming the `Into` trait is implemented on `Borrow<Y>`:

```
fn foo<T: Into<X>>(x: T)
```

Is there a way to write a function which accepts `X`, `&X`, `Y` and `&Y` using only standard traits? I can do it using custom traits, but using standard ones would be much better.

I tried:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn foo<TT: Into<T>, T: Borrow<X>>(x: TT) {}

struct X;

fn main() {
    foo(X);
}
```

But I get:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: std::borrow::Borrow<X>`
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     foo(X);
  |     ^^^
  |
  = note: required by `foo`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is disallowed because there's the possibility of multiple paths. For example, the type passed in might implement `Into<A>` **and** `Into<B>`. If  both `A` and `B` implement `Borrow<X>`, it would be ambiguous which conversion would be appropriate.

As the error message states, you can use type annotations (a.k.a. the *turbofish*) to tell the compiler which intermediate type you wish to convert into:

```
foo::<_, X>(X);
```

Comment: Is there some way to hint the compiler? Or custom traits is way to go here?

Comment: Yep, that does not seem very ergonomic (which was original intention of acceptation many things at once anyway). I will go with custom traits then.

Comment: @usamec it kind of feels like you might be on the edge of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) — what are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: Wrapper around this: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/release/2.2/Source/CNTKv2LibraryDll/API/CNTKLibrary.h

Comment: Which function, specifically?

Comment: All of them. The problem is you have function like plus, which has signature:
fn (x: Variable, y: Variable) -> FunctionPtr

But FunctionPtr can be converted into Variable (in C++).

Comment: But maybe the solution is to not allow borrow and go only with .clone (since everything in that lib is shared_ptr anyway).

Comment: @usamec You can also `impl<'a> From<&'a Variable> for Variable` as well as `From<FunctionPtr>` and `From<&'a FunctionPtr>`, as appropriate.