# Generic cloneable/movable parameter as function argument

Tags: generics, rust

For an arbitrary struct that implements `Clone`, I would like to have a single generic function that takes either:

- a `&MyStruct` in which case it can be conditionally cloned by the function
- a `MyStruct` in which case the clone is unnecessary since it can be moved

I've implemented this on my own:

```
use std::clone::Clone;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    value: u64,
}

impl Clone for MyStruct {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        println!("cloning {:?}", self);
        MyStruct { value: self.value }
    }
}

trait TraitInQuestion<T> {
    fn clone_or_no_op(self) -> T;
}

impl TraitInQuestion<MyStruct> for MyStruct {
    fn clone_or_no_op(self) -> MyStruct {
        self
    }
}

impl<'a> TraitInQuestion<MyStruct> for &'a MyStruct {
    fn clone_or_no_op(self) -> MyStruct {
        self.clone()
    }
}

fn test<T: TraitInQuestion<MyStruct>>(t: T) {
    let owned = t.clone_or_no_op();
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyStruct { value: 8675309 };

    println!("borrowing to be cloned");
    test(&a);

    println!("moving");
    test(a);
}
```

and the output is as expected:

```
borrowing to be cloned
cloning MyStruct { value: 8675309 }
moving
```

Is this functionality already derived somehow by implementing `Clone`? If not, [`std::borrow::ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) sounds like what I want, but I can't get it to work:

```
use std::clone::Clone;
use std::borrow::Borrow;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    value: u64,
}

impl Clone for MyStruct {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        println!("cloning {:?}", self);
        MyStruct { value: self.value }
    }
}

fn test<T: ToOwned<Owned = MyStruct>>(a: T) {
    let owned = a.to_owned();
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyStruct { value: 8675309 };

    println!("borrowing to be cloned");
    test(&a);

    println!("moving");
    test(a);
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyStruct: std::borrow::Borrow<T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:1
   |
16 | / fn test<T: ToOwned<Owned = MyStruct>>(a: T) {
17 | |     let owned = a.to_owned();
18 | | }
   | |_^ the trait `std::borrow::Borrow<T>` is not implemented for `MyStruct`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where MyStruct: std::borrow::Borrow<T>` bound
   = note: required by `std::borrow::ToOwned`
```

Doing what the compiler suggests by changing `test`:

```
fn test<T: ToOwned<Owned = MyStruct>>(a: T) -> ()
where
    MyStruct: Borrow<T>,
{
    let owned = a.to_owned();
}
```

And the resulting error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:27:10
   |
27 |     test(&a);
   |          ^^ expected struct `MyStruct`, found &MyStruct
   |
   = note: expected type `MyStruct`
              found type `&MyStruct`
```

If I try to implement `ToOwned` for `&MyStruct`

```
impl<'a> ToOwned for &'a MyStruct {
    type Owned = MyStruct;

    fn to_owned(&self) -> Self::Owned {
        self.clone()
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::borrow::ToOwned` for type `&MyStruct`:
  --> src/main.rs:16:1
   |
16 | / impl<'a> ToOwned for &'a MyStruct {
17 | |     type Owned = MyStruct;
18 | |
19 | |     fn to_owned(&self) -> Self::Owned {
20 | |         self.clone()
21 | |     }
22 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `alloc`
```

Comment: Are you already familiar with `Cow`?

Comment: Highly related: [Is there a way to write a function which accepts a reference, a move, or a conversion using only traits from the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47225805/155423)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of `Cow`.. That's pretty much what I was looking for, must have missed it. Although, it does seem unnecessary to wrap an input in an enum in some cases (i.e. `Cow` is to dynamic dispatch as my `TraitInQuestion` is to static dispatch, if that analogy makes sense)

Answer (score 2):

As @Shepmaster pointed out there is [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html); but you'd need to manually create the `Cow::Borrowed(&a)` or `Cow::Owned(a)` instances, and the wrapped (`Owned`) type must always implement `Clone` (for `T: ToOwned<Owned=T>`).

(The `Clone` for `ToOwned::Owned` might not be strictly necessary with custom `ToOwned` implementations; but `.borrow().to_owned()` acts like a `.clone()`, so there is no reason to hide it.)

Your own trait is a nice start for an alternative, although you should use generic implementations.  That way you don't require a type to implement `Clone` as long as you don't pass a reference:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b209753a9c1439b7fc60773c6c48a755&version=stable)

```
trait CloneOrNoOp<T> {
    fn clone_or_no_op(self) -> T;
}

impl<T> CloneOrNoOp<T> for T {
    fn clone_or_no_op(self) -> T {
        self
    }
}

impl<'a, T: Clone> CloneOrNoOp<T> for &'a T {
    fn clone_or_no_op(self) -> T {
        self.clone()
    }
}

struct MyStructNoClone;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    value: u64,
}

impl Clone for MyStruct {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        println!("cloning {:?}", self);
        MyStruct { value: self.value }
    }
}

fn test<T: CloneOrNoOp<MyStruct>>(t: T) {
    let _owned = t.clone_or_no_op();
}

// if `I` implement `Clone` this takes either `&I` or `I`; if `I` doesn't
// implement `Clone` it still will accept `I` (but not `&I`).
fn test2<I, T: CloneOrNoOp<I>>(t: T) {
    let _owned: I = t.clone_or_no_op();
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyStruct { value: 8675309 };

    println!("borrowing to be cloned");
    test(&a);
    // cannot infer `I`, could be `&MyStruct` or `MyStruct`:
    // test2(&a);
    test2::<MyStruct,_>(&a);
    test2::<&MyStruct,_>(&a);

    println!("moving");
    test(a);

    let a = MyStructNoClone;
    test2(&a);
    // the previous line is inferred as ("cloning" the reference):
    test2::<&MyStructNoClone,_>(&a);
    // not going to work (because it can't clone):
    // test2::<MyStructNoClone,_>(&a);

    test2(a);
}
```

Sadly it seems impossible for now to base `CloneOrNoOp` on `ToOwned` (instead of `Clone`) like this:

```
impl<'a, B> CloneOrNoOp<B::Owned> for &'a B
where
    B: ToOwned,
{
    fn clone_or_no_op(self) -> B::Owned {
        self.to_owned()
    }
}
```

The compiler sees conflicting implementations of "`CloneOrNoOp<&_>` for type `&_`" (someone crazy might implement `ToOwned for Foo { type Owned = &'static Foo; ... }`; traits can't distinguish implementations based on lifetime differences).

But similar to `ToOwned` you can implement specific customizations, like:

```
impl<'a> CloneOrNoOp<String> for &'a str {
    fn clone_or_no_op(self) -> String {
        self.to_owned()
    }
}
```

Now you can pass any of `&str`, `&String` or `String` if you want to get a `String`:

```
test2::<String,_>("abc");
test2::<String,_>(&String::from("abc"));
test2::<String,_>(String::from("abc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Into` trait to get what you want ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b9a80718a07cb2745265de2f1faffce2)).

```
fn test(t: impl Into<MyStruct>) { ... }
```

Because `impl Into<T> for T` already exists in the standard library, you only need to provide an `impl Into<MyStruct> for &'_ MyStruct`, which is simple given that `MyStruct` is `Clone`:

```
impl Into<MyStruct> for &'_ MyStruct {
    fn into(self) -> MyStruct {
        self.clone()
    }
}

fn test(t: impl Into<MyStruct>) {
    let owned = t.into();
}
```

As a bonus, if you want to use `t` as a reference and only sometimes clone it, you can add `AsRef<MyStrcut>` to the mix:

```
impl AsRef<MyStruct> for MyStruct {
    #[inline]
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &MyStruct {
        self
    }
}

fn test(t: impl Into<MyStruct> + AsRef<MyStruct>) {
    let t_ref = t.as_ref();

    if t_ref.value > 3 {
        let owned = t.into();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it implementing your own generic trait. The trait I used has two functions:

- for moving/cloning value;
- for getting reference.
  Thus you can write a function which either move or references a parameter and gets a reference of moves/clones it on demand.

This trait can be implemented for any moved value of type `T` and for any referenced value of type `&T`. Thus it can be easily used as a library with any type which implements `Clone`. Trait needs to be parameterized by target type `T` in order to implement it for both cases.

Trait implementation:

```rs
trait RefOrValue<T> {
    fn as_value(self) -> T;
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T;
}

impl<T> RefOrValue<T> for T {
    fn as_value(self) -> T {
        self
    }

    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T {
        self
    }
}

impl<T: Clone> RefOrValue<T> for &T {
    fn as_value(self) -> T {
        self.clone()
    }

    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T {
        *self
    }
}
```

Your example rewritten using `RefOrValue` trait:

```
use std::clone::Clone;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    value: u64,
}

impl Clone for MyStruct {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        println!("cloning {:?}", self);
        MyStruct { value: self.value }
    }
}

fn test<T: RefOrValue<MyStruct>>(t: T) {
    let owned = t.as_value();
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyStruct { value: 8675309 };

    println!("borrowing to be cloned");
    test(&a);

    println!("moving");
    test(a);
}
```

and output:

```
borrowing to be cloned
cloning MyStruct { value: 8675309 }
moving
```

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec9a45b5a74fc6153f0f0718c5341b40)